# How can i make the google maps view always appearing at the bottom of my layout?

Tags: android, google-maps, layout, view

I want the map appearing fixed at the bottom of the screen and the ScrollView only allowing the scroll before it. The problem is that when I have more than x TextViews (in the ScrollView ), the map disappears from the screen and, I cannot see him not even by scrolling tothe bottom.

I have a ScrollView containing several LinearLayouts with TextViews and at the end the mapview like this:`

```
            ...

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/details_neighbours_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/details_separator_height"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/historic_margin_separator_medium"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/neighbours_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/neighbours"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_light_grey_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/primary_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/neighbours_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/color_light_grey_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tertiary_text_size" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Map view -->
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/details_neighbours_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/neighbours_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="abc"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/neighbours_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:text="xyz" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a RelativeLayout as parent , then add the MapView with atribute

```
alignParentBottom=true
```

this and some other attribute should give you the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

          <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            >
            <!-- Your TextViews -->
        </ScrollView>

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```